# how to prevent duplicate values for people and group column sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, spservices, jquery-ui

I've column in a list where we are adding the user name(column type = user and group). If the user is already added in the list and same user if I want to save I should get error message user already exit using javascript/jquery or OOTB.

Answer (score 1):

OOTB way to achieve this is to make the User Name column as unique. This is only possible if the column is single select person or group column.

[image]

Comment: before saving I want alert message user already avilable..